# Can anyone explain why my Merge Sort is not working?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, recursion, mergesort

**Can anyone please explain why this is not working? I'm having trouble getting the numbers in my array to be sorted and placed into the empty b array. I've searched high and low but there seems to be something that eludes me, my fellow cod3rz!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge(int array[], int low, int mid, int high);
void midpoint(int array[], int low, int high);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int b[100];

    int array[] = { 13, 23, 37, 45, 55, 68, 79, 93};
    int arrayLength = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);


    for (int i =0 ; i < arrayLength; i++){
        for ( int j= 1 + i ; j < arrayLength; j++){

            midpoint(&array[i], i ,j );{

            }
        printf("%d\n", *b);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void merge(int array[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[100];
    int b[100];
    int i = low;
    int b[100];
    int j = mid + 1;
    int b[100];
    int k = 0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (array[i] <= array[j])
            b[k++] = array[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = array[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        b[k++] = array[i++];

    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = array[j++];

    k--;
    while (k > 0) {
        array[low + k] = b[k];
        k --;
    }

}

void midpoint(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (high + low)/2;
        midpoint(array, low, mid);
        midpoint(array, mid + 1, high);
        merge(array, low, mid, high);
    }

}
```

Comment: John McMahon, hey man are you sure about that? I was taught that in C to get the length of an array you get the sizeof the array and divide by the size of the first element to get the length.

Comment: That's the way I get the length of an array too. I often create a macro to make it simpler, e.g. `#define LEN(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))`. You just need to remember that it doesn't work on function parameters.

Comment: If interested, you might want to consider a bottom up merge sort, which skips all the recursive midpoint calls that repeatedly split the array via indices until sub-array size is 1 before any actual merging takes place. A bottom up merge sort starts off assuming a sub array size of 1, merging even and odd elements to produce merged sub arrays of size 2, then merges those to produce sub-arrays of size 4, and so on, until the array is sorted. Wiki link which included basic code examples: [wiki merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not passing the `b` array into the recursive calls, so there is no way it's going to be populated.
Furthermore, you should be able to do the sorting in-place in `array`, with the help of your helper array that assists the merge operations.
So, there is no need for `b` at the top level.

Your `merge()` function is a bit reversed.  What you should do is initially copy the entire `array` array into the temp `b` array, and then merge from `b` into `array`.

That way, when the algorithm is finished, `array` will be sorted at the top level, and then you have your sorted array.

Also, remove the nested for loops.  Since MergeSort is a recursive divide and conquer algorithm, you should just start with one call to `midpoint()`, and the recursion will take care of the rest if implemented correctly.

So this:

```
 for (int i =0 ; i < arrayLength; i++){
        for ( int j= 1 + i ; j < arrayLength; j++){

            midpoint(&array[i], i ,j );{

        }
        printf("%d\n", *b);
    }
```

Should just be this:

```
 midpoint(array, 0 ,arrayLength-1 );
```

Also, you have a bracket issue, take out the opening bracket from this line, and clean up closing brackets as necessary:

`midpoint(&array[i], i ,j );{`

Edit:  There was actually a lot more problems in there aside from what I outlined above.
I'm hesitant to spoon-feed you the answer since this is probably a school assignment, but since you made a good effort and your general code structure was almost correct, and it's not like you can't search and find similar solutions online, I'll go ahead and post this.

Here is a working solution that properly implements the MergeSort algorithm that is based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge(int *array, int low, int mid, int high);
void midpoint(int *array, int low, int high);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int array[] = { 100, 13, 44, 23, 22, 37, 3, 45, 2, 55, 68, 1, 79, 93, 4};
    int arrayLength = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    //start the recursive calls
    midpoint(array, 0 ,arrayLength-1 );

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ ){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}


void merge(int *array, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[100];

    //copy the current elements into temp array
    int v;
    for (v = low; v <= high; v++){
        b[v] = array[v];
    }

    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = low;

    //merge left side and right side into array in sorted order
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (b[i] <= b[j])
            array[k++] = b[i++];
        else
            array[k++] = b[j++];
    }

    //The left side might have left-over elements
    while (i <= mid)
        array[k++] = b[i++];


}

void midpoint(int *array, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (high + low)/2;
        midpoint(array, low, mid);
        midpoint(array, mid + 1, high);
        merge(array, low, mid, high);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
13
22
23
37
44
45
55
68
79
93
100
```

Comment: Daniel Nugent, That was really awesome of you! I realize now that I was silly to nest a for loop when calling the midpoint. I'm going to look through your code and study it to make sure I understand the concept behind merge sort properly. Thanks again, you're a real pal and friend. I love you.

Comment: Also I would gladly upvote you but I cannot unfortunately because I lack the reputation. Worry not, Daniel Nugent, for life shall repay you tenfold for your generosity. May your rambles be sweet and your reveries merry!